# Most frequent value in delphi array

Tags: arrays, delphi, tcolor

I have an array of TColor in Delphi where I need to find the most frequent value in.

I was thinking about, if there was something similar to java.util.Collections.frequency() in Delphi, but did not find anything useful yet.

Do I really have to find the most frequent value on my own?

Comment: Sort the array and then a one pass loop can find the most frequent value. Not that difficult.

Comment: There's nothing in any runtime libs supplied with the product that will do that. Create a dictionary, `TDictionary<TColor, Integer>`. Walk over the array and every time you find a new color add that color to the dictionary with value 1. When you find a repeated color, increment its value.

Comment: @LURD Sorting is O(n log n), but the dict approach is O(n)

Comment: @David Heffernan For some (not large) array size hidden constant for hashing such simple type might be higher than `logn`

Comment: @MBo True. But it tends to be large data that hurts perf rather than small data. On the other hand, if you just have a lot of small data sets, then the overhead of hashing could be too much.

Comment: @impiouz How large you array is? Do you expect that some value might occupy more than half of array (majority element)?

Comment: @MBo the array may hold up to multiple ten thousands entries. It's possible that a value occupies more than half of the array, but not for sure.

Comment: In that case you'll want to avoid coping and sorting, and use the dict approach. You will also need to think about normalising the TColor values. Some values are sentinels (e.g. clWindow) that you might want to convert to RGB first. That is if it is plausible that your data can contain these sentinels.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thx for your answer, I'm going to try the dict approach. I guess it's unlikely that I'll get sentinels because the array originally comes from the TBitMap's Pixels property.

Comment: Right about that. Scanline would be more efficient FWIW

Comment: @impiouz Are you aware about Scanline? (if interested in speed)